# Error on folder delete in Azure Portal Console

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I'm attempting to manually delete a folder in my app service in Azure Portal's console. The console I'm talking about is in the portal, go to App Services > (name) > Deployment slots > (slot) > Console.

(Deploy failed to delete folder, fix is to manually delete and re-run.)

When I attempt to delete the folder, I get this:

[image: azure console screenshot]

Basically, I enter the command to delete the folder, get an "are you sure, enter Y/N", I type Y and return, and then get an error about `'Y' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. Just hitting return, not entering Y, I just get a new prompt line.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OH MY GOSH this is the stupidest thing.

Still don't know what's up with the delete in the Portal Console, but if you go to the **KUDU** console, it works just fine.

> https://{your application}-{slot}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

Comment: Which would help if Kudu weren't blowing up saying no disk space. So, how do you actually answer this question?

Comment: @ssmith what a tricky situation! is the whole app service out of space, or just the kudu section? i would it's the former, and you need to scale up the service or something first.

Comment: It's still failing intermittently with 500 errors on deploys. Doing an `rm -rf` in the deployments folder seems to help but it's still aggravating.